# DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. - how to find where the "function:" is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I recently updated my node to 7.2.1 and noticed that there is a warning coming:

> (node:4346) DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.

What is this `4346` for? I only have 2000 lines in the js file, so it can't be a line-number. Where can I find the code?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use either the [`--trace-deprecation`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_deprecation) or [`--throw-deprecation`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_throw_deprecation) options.

For example:

```
node --trace-deprecation app.js
```

or:

```
node --throw-deprecation app.js
```

The first option will log a stack trace and the second will throw an error (which, if not caught, will also log a stack trace).

Also, `4346` is most likely the process ID.

Comment: got. I should use `writeFileSync` rather than `writeFile` :)

Comment: no, you still might prefer to use the non blocking version, even if you aren't interested by the result. just pass function(){} for the callback. and yes, that number is the process id.

Comment: Same for me. Changed writeFile to writeFileSync.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include a callback function for the Asynchronous method (`writeFile` in your case).

For example

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt',data,'utf8',(error)=>{
    // your code goes here
});
```

where

```
(error) => { });
```

is the callback function.

From Version: v7.0.0
The callback parameter is no longer optional. Not passing it will emit a deprecation warning.

Please refer: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback
for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the following two methods, myself.

## 1:

```
fs.writeFile('example.md', data, (error) => { console.log("Error!"); });
```

## 2:

```
fs.writeFile('example.md', data, function (err) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you have not catch error by using err callback
use like below in your code

```
fs.write('./abc.txt',function(err){
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('success.!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just mention:

```
fs.writeFile('<your file name>',<your data>,function(){});
```

here, you need to mention function(){} as this is a callback() to write text in asynchronous manner.

Using writeFileSync will make an synchronous call

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning

```
[DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

and had the same problem of not knowing which part of my code was causing it. So I looked at code I had recently modified and saw this statement-suspect:

```
 Fs . writeFile (path, aString, cb, encoding);
```

Problem was the cb (= 'callback') and the encoding arguments are in wrong order.
I got rid of the warning simply by changing the above to:

```
 Fs . writeFile (path, aString, encoding,  cb);
```

But the problem really is with the ERRONEOUS warning-message.
I WAS  passing in a callback-argument but just one which
was not a Function but a String.  So if the warning had 
said

```
"WWARNING: calling fs.writeFile() with a string-argument 
 where a function is expected"
```

... it would have been obvious what was happening. Of course
a line-number in the warning would be nice as well.

So the point is I was NOT calling writeFile() without
a callback-argument, which is deprecated. I was
calling writeFile() WITH A WRONG TYPE OF ARGUMENT.
That should be an ERROR, not a warning.