# DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron

i am working on electron + angularjs . and i start getting the problem of `DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.` when i use [id3js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/id3js) to read the tags from mp3 file .

```
id3({file: pathtofile,type: id3.OPEN_LOCAL}, function(err, tags) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(tags);}
});
```

the code retun the tags from the mp3 file but keep generate this deprecation warning

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to know why i get this error and how to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. - how to find where the "function:" is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195580/deprecationwarning-calling-an-asynchronous-function-without-callback-is-depreca)

Comment: It looks like you'll have to use the advice from the link in Mistalis' comment and generate a stack trace for who exactly is calling an API without a required callback.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

well i fix the problem by changing the id3js library  file 
they use `fs.open` so i change it to be

```
fs.openSync(self.file, 'r', function(err, fd) {
                        if(err) {
                            return callback(err);
                        }
                        self.fd = fd;
                        callback();
                    });
```

and no more problem , i will submit this on git

Comment: This is a BAD fix.  Except perhaps in your server startup code, you never want to use synchronous file I/O as that can ruin the scalability of your server.  If the id3js code was using `fs.open()`, it had to be using a callback.  So, what you've shown does not yet make sense.  If you show us the code in id3js that is causing problems (in your question), we can likely help you with a recommended and good fix.

Comment: Plus `fs.openSync()` does not even take a callback so this code won't work at all.  It may remove the warning, but it won't function properly.

Comment: @jfriend00 the code in id3js 
`fs.open(self.file, 'r', function(err, fd) {
      if(err) {
       return callback(err);
      }
      self.fd = fd;
      callback();
     }); `

Comment: There's no missing callback in that code.  So, the problem lies elsewhere, perhaps inside whatever callback is passed to this function because your attempt at a fix actually stops the callback from getting called.