# How to solve this error with async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, try-catch

I'm starting in node.js and I'm trying to use try..catch with file system methods. This is what I have:

```
let fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');

let buf = new Buffer(1024);

const open = util.promisify(fs.open);
const read = util.promisify(fs.read);
const close = util.promisify(fs.close)

async function main(){
  console.log("Going to open an existing file");
  try{
    const fd = await open('input.txt', 'r+');
    console.log("File opened successfully!");
    console.log("Going to read the file");

    try{
      await read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0);
      if(bytes > 0) 
         console.log(buf.slice(0, bytes).toString());
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log("Error");
   } 
 }
 catch(e){
   console.log("Error");
 }
} 
main();
console.log("Program ended");
```

When I execute it goes to the second catch and doesn't print anything.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. - how to find where the "function:" is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195580/deprecationwarning-calling-an-asynchronous-function-without-callback-is-depreca)

Comment: Why are you passing all those arguments to `read()` instead of `buffer = await read(fd);`? Doesn't `fs.readFile` just want a path or buffer?

Comment: read not = readFile

Comment: @Keith see -> `const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);`

Comment: Yes, I know that with 'readFile' it works, but I wanted to do with 'read' only

Comment: @JasonMort, I understand that, but `read` is a promisified version of `fs.readFile`, so you need to pass arguments into `read` like you would `readFile`. You're passing it 5 arguments, why? You can use `read()` like this: `let buffer = await read(fd);`

Comment: Also, where is `bytes` defined?

Comment: I edited the code, the bytes I thought that would came of the callback 'read'

Comment: It'd be helpful if your error messages were more descriptive. Try logging e.message or just e.

Comment: @Mark_M  Indeed, so surely it's.. `const read = util.promisify(fs.read);`  readFile doesn't take a file descriptor, it takes a filename..

Comment: @Keith yes, the edit made things a lot clearer. FYI https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback: *"path <string> | <Buffer> | <URL> | <integer> filename or **file descriptor**"* I think that's been the case since V. 5.

Comment: @Mark_M  I think your missing my point, ignore the fd, readFile does not take buffer offsets, that Op is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your updated code, the only error I'm seeing is from the undeclared `bytes` variable.

`await read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0);` will return a value that has:

```
{ 
  buffer: bufferData,
  bytesRead: numberOfBytes
}
```

So in you async code you need to get those and use them:

```
try{
  let ret = await read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0);
  if(ret.bytesRead > 0) 
     console.log(buf.slice(0, ret.bytesRead).toString());
}
```

Of course, you can also just print the buffer returned from `read()`.

It will also be helpful in the `catch` blocks to print the errors:

```
catch(e){
  console.log("Error", e);
}
```

Also, if you want the `console.log` at the end to be at the right time you should use something like:

```
main().then(() => console.log("Program ended")) ;
```