# node.js warning when calling to function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've the following code which works

```
if (fs.existsSync(dirName)) {
    __writeFile();
    return;
}

function __writeFile() {
    writeIntoFile(readStream, destFileName, reject);
    numOfFiles++;
}
```

But after execute it im getting warning:

> (node:3547) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous
>   function without callback is deprecated.

Any idea how to avoid this ?

update this is all the code

```
yauzl.open(filePath, (err, zipFile) => {
            if (err) {
                __rejectAndLog(err);
                return;
            }
            zipFile.on('entry', __processEntry.bind(null, zipFile))
                .once('error', __rejectAndLog)
                .once('close', () => {
                    resolve();
                });
        });

        function __processEntry(zipFile, entry) {
            if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
                return;
            }
            zipFile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
                if (err) {
                    __rejectAndLog(err);
                    return;
                }
                //Path to drop the files
                let destFileName =  '/' + entry.fileName;
                let dirName = path.join(res);
                if (fs.existsSync(dirName)) {
                    __writeFile();
                    return;
                }
                mkdirp(dirName, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        __rejectAndLog(err);
                    } else {
                        __writeFile();
                    }
                });
                function __writeFile() {
                    writeIntoFile(readStream, destFileName, reject);
                    numOfFiles++;
                }
            });
        }
```

as requested this is the content of write into file

```
    function writeIntoFile(readStream, filePath, onError) {
        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            fs.chmod(filePath, '777');
        }
        var ws = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        ws.on('error', function (error) {
            onError(error);
        });
        readStream.pipe(ws);
    };
```

update2

I try to change it according the answer below and its not working (and where should I put the mode 777)

```
        function writeIntoFile(readStream, filePath, onError) {
        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            fs.chmod(filePath, 0o777, function (err) {

                var ws = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
                ws.on('error', function (error) {
                    onError(error);
                });
                readStream.pipe(ws);

            });

        }

    };
```

Comment: are you sure the error isn't within `writeIntoFile`?

Comment: I don't see an asynchronous function here, so I would guess it's in your `writeIntoFile` function. To remove the warning, add the argument callback as the warning suggests.

Comment: @Evert - can you please provide example?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - Im not sure, while debug it happen when the return is executed and im getting to the previous function (up)

Comment: add the code contents of that function to your question so we can see.

Comment: Where is the contents of `writeIntoFile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated. - how to find where the "function:" is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195580/deprecationwarning-calling-an-asynchronous-function-without-callback-is-depreca)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - done, please have a look

Comment: @Evert - please see my update

Comment: [`fs.chmod()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback) is the culprit.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - so do you think that this is the problem ?  if so there is a solution for it ?

Comment: @JennyM read the documentation, understand how it works, and use the callback function to wait until the file permissions are actually changed before creating the write stream.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - i've change it according to your suggestion but it doesnt work, please see my update

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - can you please show what should I fix? i try someting else(see my update ) and now I dont see the warning but it doesnt work..., btw I use fs with bluebird promisify ...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I've change it to octal as you said and still I dont see the warning :) but it stops working :(

Comment: "It stops working" is not a descriptive problem statement. Are there any errors? If not, have you stepped through your program with a debugger to ensure that everything is being called, and in the proper order? If so, are the file permissions being modified? What is broken?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - there is no error but it doesnt create the file as before, does the code in my last update looks OK? is there is something missing ?